# "macro names must be identifiers"

Tags: c++, arduino

I get the above error message with the code that's shown below. It's for use with a JSN-SR04T sensor. I'm using an Arduino Uno with IDE version 1.8.2.0.

I changed pin numbers and took out all blank spaces just in case there were any embedded characters. Still get the error. Not sure of what else to do. Any suggestions?

Code:

```cpp
/*
 * Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 and Arduino Tutorial
 *
 * Created by Dejan Nedelkovski,
 * www.HowToMechatronics.com
 *
*/.
#define ECHOPIN 10
#define TRIGPIN 9

const int TRIGPIN = 9;
const int ECHOPIN = 10;
long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
  pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);
  distance= duration*0.034/2;
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Comment: at which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 3):

If [this](http://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/) is the original code you copied, then you can see that there are no macro definitions. In your example there are two macro definitions with the same name as the following `const int` declarations:

```
#define ECHOPIN 10
#define TRIGPIN 9

const int TRIGPIN = 9;
const int ECHOPIN = 10;
```

The [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) will substitute every `ECHOPIN` and `TRIGPIN` macros with their value. Therefore after the preprocessor finished its job, the code snippet above will look like:

```
const int 9 = 9;
const int 10 = 10;
```

Remove either the macros or the `const int` declarations from your code and it may work.

Answer (score 3):

```
 * www.HowToMechatronics.com
 *
*/.
```

What is this dot doing after `/`?

Comment: This *is* the answer. Remove the dot and the double definitions of ECHOPIN and TRIGPIN and it will compile...